# Angular CRUD, update view when backend/database changes ($resource and REST)

Tags: angularjs, crud

I am currently making an application in angular which does this:

(On page load) Make an api call in angular controller (to symfony2 end point) to get: `items`.

```
$scope.items = ItemsService.query(function(data){
    $scope.loading = false;
}, function(err){
    $scope.loading = false;
});
```

`items` is an array containing many `item` objects.
Each `item` contains parameters e.g. `item.param1` `item.param2`.

I have built it in a similar way to this tutorial:
http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/
i.e. The angular controller calls a service which calls the (symfony2) backend api endpoint.
The endpoint passes back `items` which is gets from a database. Items are then put into the view using ng-repeat (`item in items`).

This all works fine.

Now, I have a button (in the ng-repeat) which effectively causes a PUT request to be made to (another symfony2 endpoint), thus updating `item.param1`in the database. This also happens in the tutorial I linked to.

The problem is that (in my application and in the tutorial) I have to again make an api call which updates ALL the items, in order to see the change.
I want to just update the data in the view (immediately) for one object without having to fetch them all again.
i.e. something like:

```
$scope.items[4] = Items.get({id: item.id}, function(){});
```

Except the application array key isn't known so I cant do that.
(so something like: `$scope.items.findTheOriginalItem(item) = Items.get({id: item.id}, function(){});`.

Another possible solution (which seems like it may be the best?). I have looked here:
http://teropa.info/blog/2014/01/26/the-three-watch-depths-of-angularjs.html
And tried doing the equality $watch: `$scope.$watch(…, …, true);`. Thus using watch to see when the `item` sub-array is updated. This doesn't seem to update the data in the view though (even though it is updating in the database).

Any advice on the best way of doing this (and how to do it) would be great! Thanks!

Comment: If you know what is changing on your item why you need to made a request on the server? Just update the view (since the server will be updated anyway you will be consistent I guess)

Comment: I need to make a request to the server so the server can update the database!
The problem is that when the database is updated it isn't being reflected immediately in the view (which is why I need to make another call to re-get the items (preferably not make this call though and just reflect in the view, as the correct data is already there))

Comment: did you tried to use `scope.digest()` after the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the button click should use `ng-click` to execute a function and pass the item to that function. Example:

`...ng-repeat="item in items"...
<button type="button" ng-click="updateItem(item)">Update</button
...`

Then in the function you have the exact item that you want to update. If you are using $resources, it would be something like:

`$scope.updateItem = function(item) { item.$update(...); };`

Unless I didn't understand you

Comment: The problem I'm having now though is that it is showing as updated in the view, and it is apparently sending PUT requests (can see using chrome's network tab), but it is not being received by the backend. (GET requests are though). The documentation and the tutorial is slightly confusing because one says use .update and the other says use $update (.update passing the object to the service instead of .$update on the object itself is what I'm using). Any ideas on why the backend isn't receiving any data from the frontend for put requests?

Comment: This is the code:

ItemsService.update({ id: item.id }, item, function(){
    $scope.loading = false;
}, function(err){
    $scope.loading = false;
    item.param1 = true; //if failed set back to true
});

Comment: Ah I see what is going on now, it is a misconfiguration in the backend relating to PUT! Thanks for the help!